# Servlet: return http500 when new URL(url);

Tags: java, url, servlets, soap

I want to send an soap request to a webservice in servlet.

But I got a http500 response when `URL url = new URL(webServiceURL);` was executed.

But I can visit the webServiceURL via IE.

Could you tell me why?

Comment: It depends on what you tried to do with the `URL` object. More logs would certainly help.

Comment: logs:java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://..../webService

Comment: What page you get when you visit the `webServiceURL` with browser ?